# Gsap Animation in Next.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with this gsap animation used for this site. The scroll animation on the x works but I have a jerky problem, when the scroll-section enters the viewport, it jerks and is not smooth. How could I solve this? I tried changing the pin which might give me this problem but still it continues. Thanks so much to anyone who can give me some advice

I leave you the code here:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";
import styles from './scroll.style.css';


function ScrollSection() {
  const sectionRef = useRef(null);
  const triggerRef = useRef(null);

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  useEffect(() => {
    const pin = gsap.fromTo(
      sectionRef.current,
      {
        translateX: 0,
      },
      {
        translateX: "-300vw",
        ease: "none",
        duration: 1,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: triggerRef.current,
          start: "center center",
          end: "2000 top",
          scrub: 0.6,
          pin: true,
        },
      }
    );
    return () => {
      {}
      pin.kill();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="scroll-section-outer">
      {}

      {}
      <div ref={triggerRef}>           
       <h3 className="introduction">Mytext</h3>
       <div class="linea_div"><hr className="linea"/></div>
        <div ref={sectionRef} className="scroll-section-inner">
          <div className="scroll-section">
            <p class="Project_title">title1</p>
            <h3 className="scroll_gallery">Section 1</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="scroll-section">
          <p class="Project_title">title2</p>
            <h3 className="scroll_gallery">Section 2</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="scroll-section">
          <p class="Project_title">title3</p>
            <h3 className="scroll_gallery">Section 3</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="scroll-section">
          <p class="Project_title">title4</p>
            <h3 className="scroll_gallery">Section 4</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="scroll-section">
          <p class="Project_title">title5</p>
            <h3 className="scroll_gallery">Section 4</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default ScrollSection;
```

Style:

```css
.introduction {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: calc(1.675rem + 1.43158vw);
  line-height: 1.3em;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.linea_div {
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;;
}
.linea {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.scroll-section-outer {
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-section-inner {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.scroll-section {
  height: 50vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
}
.scroll_gallery {
  height: 45vh;
  width: 30vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .scroll_gallery {
    width: 75vw;
  }
}

.scroll-section h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.Project_title {
  color: #fff;
}
```